# get annotated object instance of class with doctrine annotations library

Tags: php, annotations, doctrine

I am trying to write my first custom annotation class. I've added `@Foo(foo="bar")` annotation in this entity.

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use App\Foo;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\UserRepository")
 * @Foo(foo="bar")
 */
class User implements \JsonSerializable
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $username;

    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getUsername(): ?string
    {
        return $this->username;
    }

    public function setUsername(string $username): self
    {
        $this->username = $username;

        return $this;
    }

    public function jsonSerialize()
    {
        return [
            'username' => $this->username,
        ];
    }
}
```

and created this class:

```
<?php

namespace App;

/**
 * @Annotation
 */
class Foo
{
    public $foo;

    public function __construct(array $params = [])
    {
        throw new \RuntimeException(
            'Oops! ' . var_export($params, true)
        );
    }
}
```

And the exception output this:

```
Oops! array (
    'allow' => 'username',
)
```

But this means I've only the possibility to send data. How can I, from `App\Foo`, get `App\Entity\User` class? Actually I need to send class as parameter. Is there another possibility?